# Does selenium IDE supports pass and fail status report?

Tags: selenium, automation

I have done automation using selenium IDE for my web application. But I couldn't get the pass/fail status report. Please show me how to get the status report in selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link:

https://www.quora.com/Does-selenium-IDE-support-pass-and-fail-status-reports

It has the Youtube link which answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

- 1st thing selenium IDE can show you some summery like how many tests
  passed and failed but it cannot generate enhanced reports.
- for example: selenium IDE have set of test cases in its lift side panel and and they are enclosed in test suites most probably, and each test case have test steps as rows in selenium IDE body.
- So while execution if a test step passes then its indicates in green color and red if fails, and if a step fails then test case in left panel indicates in red color and at bottom of the left panel you will see a number in green color which indicates passed tests and a number in red color which indicates failed ones
- this is the only way it shows the summery of the execution, but you can't generate full length reports because simply selenium IDE is not meant for that purpose
- most of the times people use selenium IDE for simple automation tasks where they don't expect any reporting like things, if there is a complex or more requirements of automation one has to move from selenium IDE to WebDriver